# React Native dropdown does not work when data value is empty

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, dropdown

after triggering the action create I'm trying to fill the dropdown component with my object from Reducer. I tried but I couldn't.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';
import { recuperarDisciplinas } from '../actions/AutenticacaoActions';

class cadastroMateria extends Component {

componentDidMount(){

 const { disciplina } = this.props;   
 this.props.recuperarDisciplinas({ disciplina }) 
}

render() {
   return (

  <View>

// First it hits here once before going to componentDidMount and at that moment as the 
// 'discipline' is still empty, the error dropdown 

    <Dropdown label="Disciplinas" data={this.props.disciplina } />
  </View>       
  );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
{
    disciplina: state.AutenticacaoReducer.disciplina,
}
);

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { recuperarDisciplinas })(cadastroMateria);
```

I researched to see if it was possible for the dropdown to accept null at least the first time, so that when 'discipline' comes populated it can be filled in later, but I couldn't. I tried several other things but I have no idea how to solve this problem. who can give me a help I thank

Comment: Idk the answear for your problem, but...
Feels like you are learning about react and such...
Tip: use function components with hooks, seems React classes are quickly being left behind

Answer (score 0):

In case he brings the objects I want from firebase, my difficulty is that because he is asynchronous he gives an error in the dropdown because the 'data' is empty.
I also tried it this way, but the error persists, and for the rest, this is right.

```
_recuperarDisciplinas(){

 const { disciplina } = this.props;

 this.props.recuperarDisciplinas({ disciplina }) 

/*this 'dropdown.disciplinas' at the beginning comes as false, after it passes 
through the firebase function I make the action turn it to true */

 if(this.props.dropdown_disciplinas){
    return <Dropdown label="Disciplinas" data={this.props.disciplina } />
 }
}

render() {
   return (

  <View>
{this._recuperarDisciplinas()}
  </View>
```